# EF Core - FromSql throwing invalid number when parameterizing collection of numbers

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, grpc

I am using Entity Framework Core and trying to convert a collection of integers to a string, then pass the string as a parameter to the `FromSql` function.

Here is a stripped back example of my problem:

```
IQueryable<Equipment> query = _context.Set<Equipment>();

const string s = "150999, 720045, 720046";

IQueryable<SignalGantryEquipment> filteredSignalGantryEquipments 
                = query.FromSql("select id, name from equipment " +
                                "where id in ({0}) and type = {1} " + 
                                "order by name", s, equipmentId)
                    .Select(x => new Equipment
                    {
                        Id = x.Id,
                        Name = x.Name
                    });

return filteredSignalGantryEquipments;
```

The code above I expected to work. However, I get the following error:

[image]

The problem is 100% related to parametrizing the string s as I have tested the `equipmentId`.

What I am finding very strange, is if I remove the string s as a parameter and hardcode the values in place it works as expected with no error.

```
IQueryable<SignalGantryEquipment> filteredSignalGantryEquipments 
                = query.FromSql("select id, name from signal_gantry_equipment " +
                                "where id in (150999, 720045, 720046) and equipment_type = {0} " + 
                                "order by name", equipmentId)
                    .Select(x => new SignalGantryEquipment
                    {
                        Id = x.Id,
                        Name = x.Name
                    });
```

Why is this the case, and how can I make the collection of integers as parameter?

Comment: Do you have to use raw SQL? If not this could be done a lot cleaner (imo) using Linq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the formed query will be something like below. Note that what you're trying to pass in as a set is actually just a string, where the Oracle DB provider is expecing a set of numbers (I'm assuming `int`s).

`select id, name from equipment where id in ('150999, 720045, 720046')...`

Here's an option, if you don't mind going full Linq:

```cs
var idList = new List<int>(){ 150999, 720045, 720046 };

// making some guesses on property names below
// also - is it correct to be comparing equipment type to variable named equipmentId?

return _context.Set<Equipment>()
   .Where(e => idList.Contains(e.Id) && e.EquipmentType == equipmentId)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That clears up my understanding. 
For my situation, the database I'm working with is a bit chaotic so I initally thought raw sql would work better. 
I've since changed to LINQ, taken your example, and made a few tweaks and it works great. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If my solution works for you I'd super appreciate if you accept the answer (check mark to the left of the answer). In my personal opinion, the ability to use LINQ over raw SQL is one of EF Core's greatest strengths. There's a bit of a learning curve to it, but it's a very powerful and (again - opinion) clean way of building queryables!